# One Equation One unknow but is it solvable? Floor functions

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have this equation I am trying to solve but I don't know if it can be solved (I have used quite a few math programs and they can't do it (or at least for large numbers) )

the equation is as follows:

p is a very large prime

g is a constant and a positive integer

A is a constant and a positive integer

x is the only var

((g^floor(x))-A)/p - floor(((g^x)-A)/p) =0

the second equation has the following format and i also do not how to solve this one

log(g , p*floor(x)+A) - floor(log(g , p*x+A))=0

here g, A and p are the same as last time (these two equations are linked but
Y is a var that is different from x

Is there a solution to either of these equations without brute force?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: do you set restrictions on $A,g$ ? positivity for instance, are they integer or reals ? Also what is the log function with two arguments ?

Comment: So A , g are both positive integers and the log with two arguments is just log base of first argument i.e log base g of px + A